# problem displaying ico

Tags: etherscan, ropsten, ico, cpp-ethereum

I created an ICO using ropsten (because I did not have an ETH) and when I search for my ICO on https://etherscan.io, I cannot find it.

I can only find it here: https://ropsten.etherscan.io.

Is it normal, because the ICO that I created is not a test. It is the ICO that I will launch.

Thank you for your answers.

Please excuse my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are launching an ICO in the Ropsten network it means the ICO can only take in Ropsten Ethers. Ropsten Ethers are only valid inside the Ropsten network and they are worthless.

It's good to practice running an ICO in a test network such as Ropsten but there is no point in running a real ICO in a test network. You really should run the real ICO in a real network - the main Ethereum network.

The ICO is of course only visible in Ropsten's etherscan as it only exists in the Ropsten network. Once you publish it in the main network it will be visible in the main network's etherscan.